# How to add a "Watch More" link in your videos on Facebook

Tags: facebook

I just stumble upon a video in my facebook feed which had a nifty built in feature. After the video finished playing, there was a direct link in the video to an external url.

[image]

How can I do such thing? I tried posting several videos but I never had the option to enter an external url. The regular facebook video simply restart when they are done.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a call to action to your Facebook video is simple. Once you’ve started uploading your video, simply select an option from the “Call to Action” dropdown menu in the lower left corner of the upload window. The options include Shop Now, Book Now, Learn More, Sign Up, Download, or Watch More.

[See this Screnshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KrxSX.jpg)

Answer (score -1):

This is done by specifying a `WATCH_MORE` call to action type when POSTing a video to a Page. Taking a look at [Facebook's documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/videos/):

> Call to action for someone viewing a video, such as Reply. You can add a call to action button to an uploaded video. This should be the action you want people to take when they reach the end of the video.

So your `call_to_action` parameter would probably look something like this when POSTing to your page:

```
'call_to_action': {
    'type': 'WATCH_MORE',
    'value': {
        'link': 'your_link',
        'link_description': 'your_description'
        ...etc
    }
}
```